# timestamp, modification time, and created time of a file

Tags: linux, filesystems, files

I just know that `ls -t` and `ls -f` give different sorting of files and subdirectories under a directory.

- What are the differences between timestamp, modification time, and created time of a file?
- How to get and change these kinds of information by commands?
- In terms of what kind of information do people say a file is "newer" than the other?
- What kinds of information's change will not make the
  file different?

For example, I saw someone wrote:

> By default, the rsync program only looks to see if the files are different in size and timestamp. It doesn't care which file is newer, if it is different, it gets overwritten. You can pass the '--update' flag to rsync which will cause it to skip files on the destination if they are newer than the file on the source, but only so long as they are the same type of file. What this means is that if, for example, the source file is a regular file and the destination is a symlink, the destination file will be overwritten, regardless of timestamp.

On a side note, does the file type here mean only regular file and simlink, not the type such as pdf, jpg, htm, txt etc?

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/62492/how-can-i-change-the-date-modified-created-of-a-file

Comment: Wrt the question, *"How to [] change these [mod times] by commands?"*, there is a [really good answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/62496/831935).

Answer (score 180, accepted):

There are 3 kind of "timestamps":

- Access - the last time the file was read
- Modify - the last time the file was modified (content has been modified)
- Change - the last time meta data of the file was changed (e.g. permissions)

To display this information, you can use [`stat`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stat-invocation.html) which is part of the coreutils.

`stat` will show you also some more information like the device, inodes, links, etc.

Remember that this sort of information depends highly on the filesystem and mount options. For example if you mount a partition with the `noatime` option, no access information will be written.

A utility to change the timestamps would be `touch`.
There are some arguments to decide which timestamp to change (e.g. -a for access time, -m for modification time) and to influence the parsing of a new given timestamp.
See [`man touch`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?touch) for more details.

`touch` can become handy in combination with `cp -u` (*"copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing"*) or for the creation of empty marker files.

Comment: Thanks! For rsync command, in "it doesn't care which file is newer", in terms of which kind of timestamp does it mean by "newer". Also, on a side note, does the file type that rsync cares about mean only regular file and simlink, not the type such as pdf, jpg, htm, txt etc?

Comment: Generally, reference to the time of a file is the "modified" timestamp.  For example, what you see from `ls -l`.  And the file type refers to file vs. symlink (or other types of files like directories or devices).  *Not* what the type of data in the file is (text vs. jpeg, etc).

Comment: @Tim In that context it's the modified timestamp; rsync is saying that when it's deciding if it should back up a file, it doesn't check to see if the source file has been modified more recently than the existing backup (which is common with backup programs); it just checks to see if the files have different sizes or different modification times and backs up if so

Comment: And how do I know when the file was created first? Is this information maintained somewhere at all or is lost in updates? so to say, how long the file has been in existence..?

Comment: The [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) man page describes in more detail when those timestamps are changed.

Comment: @xyz, besides the fact that some filesystems do not store a field for "create" time, some apps make it hard to maintain.  Imagine an editor that writes the data to a temp file, then renames it to the real name on save.  Just editing could nuke the data.

Comment: there is a birth time now, however, from my experimentations. it does not keep the original creation time. Birth time is the time when the file was created on the filesystem, also known as the file creation time ( crtime on EXTFS). Note that, this is not defined by POSIX; only last access time ( atime ), last modification time ( mtime ) and the inode change time ( ctime ) are mandated by POSIX

Answer (score 42):

The answer of echox is valid but I want to add information regarding file creation time.

## File System Support

Some file systems support an additional entry in the inode regarding the creation time (or birth time). I know that [ext4 supports this feature](https://www.redhat.com/archives/ext3-users/2006-October/msg00015.html) and also [JFS and BTRFS](https://lwn.net/Articles/397442/).

However most tools and API have not yet been updated to read this extra information. So even-though it could be there, it's not accessible.

For instance on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I get the following for a file I created today:

```
$ echo Just another test > /tmp/mytest
$ sleep 3
$ touch /tmp/mytest
$ sleep 2
$ cat /tmp/mytest > /dev/null
$ stat /tmp/mytest 
[...]
Access: 2012-06-05 13:33:44.279774711 +0200
Modify: 2012-06-05 13:33:34.611893317 +0200
Change: 2012-06-05 13:33:34.611893317 +0200
 Birth: -
$ sudo debugfs -R 'stat /tmp/mytest' /dev/sda1
[...]
 ctime: 0x4fcdee8e:91e30114 -- Tue Jun  5 13:33:34 2012
 atime: 0x4fcdee98:42b417dc -- Tue Jun  5 13:33:44 2012
 mtime: 0x4fcdee8e:91e30114 -- Tue Jun  5 13:33:34 2012
crtime: 0x4fcdee46:01258f1c -- Tue Jun  5 13:32:22 2012
[...]
```

You can see that the newer stat function has a birth field, though the output seems incorrect. And via debugfs we can get the information (crtime as I'm on ext4 file system).

## statx support

There is now [since Kernel 4.11, a new statx system call](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.11#statx.282.29.2C_a_modern_stat.282.29_alternative), on top of better support of [Y2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) or network file systems, it also brings a few extra features like the `btime` or birth time (creation time) access. Support for ext4 should be in the same kernel release 4.11.

There have been patches to add support to this new syscall in later Kernel releases: e.g. BTRFS and F2FS in Kernel 4.13, SMB3 in 4.14, GFS2 in 4.15, NFS in 4.16, etc.

This system call is wrapped in [GNU C library 2.28 and later](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html).

Comment: Do you know if btime remains intact when files from Windows (Creation time) are moved onto ext4 and vice versa, like mtime?

Comment: @paradroid sorry I do not know the answer. If you mean under Linux when copying a file from NTFS to ext4, one would need to look in the NTFS driver if it supports creation time. If you mean under Windows, one would need to look in the ext4 driver for Windows.

Comment: @Huygens On my system `/tmp` is a `tmpfs` so I created the `mytest` file on another ext4 LV mounted on `/myTmp`. Now let `myFile=/myTmp/mytest`, then the command `sudo debugfs -R "stat $myFile" $(findmnt -n -o source -T $myFile)` says  `/myTmp/mytest: File not found by ext2_lookup`