# What is the difference between modify and change in stat command context?

Tags: command-line, files, timestamps

The `stat` command's manual page says:

> ```
>    %x     Time of last access
>    %y     Time of last modification
>    %z     Time of last change
> ```

I cannot understand the difference between *modify* and *change*. I understand the words are synonyms (English is not my native language), but their output is different.

I tried the following command

```
stat --printf="Change %z\nAccess %x\nModify %y\n" p.txt
```

Now when I open p.txt, access time is changed, I go into insert mode, edit the file, modify and change time remains same.

```
Change 2010-10-06 12:48:39.286252389 +0500
Access 2010-10-06 12:49:14.962243456 +0500
Modify 2010-10-06 12:48:39.234498878 +0500
```

When I write the changes to file `:w`, modify and change, both change but give different values.

```
Change 2010-10-06 12:51:21.949082169 +0500
Access 2010-10-06 12:51:21.908246082 +0500
Modify 2010-10-06 12:51:21.908246082 +0500
```

So what are the meanings of "modify" and "change" in this context? That is, time of modification and change give time of which events?

Thanks

Comment: To make it even funnier, in my localized `--help` it reads something like "last modify" and "last modified" since we don't have two words for modify/change.

Comment: @CamiloMartin that is an awful disservice by the translator. If you know English, I recommend using only english environment - much easier to understand the original documentation writer's intention and also much easier to find help online.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

This has already been answered in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2464/timestamp-modification-time-and-created-time-of-a-file), which I quote (original text by [echox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1339/echox)):

> There are 3 kind of "timestamps":
>
> - Access - the last time the file was read
> - Modify - the last time the file was modified (content has been modified)
> - Change - the last time meta data of the file was changed (e.g. permissions)

[This post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385203/regarding-access-time-unix) explains the difference among the three different times from a programming interface point of view.

Comment: Thank you for not closing this as a duplicate. A websearch took me to this question, because unlike the first question you linked to, it actually contains the word 'changed'. I would also argue that the correct place for this question is indeed here, and not StackOverflow, since it's a *nix question, and not really a programming question.