# How to clean up unnecessary files

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems

Please suggest me any particular unnecessary file that I can clean to back everything to normal condition(temporarily). (i.e. any log or archieve or anything ). My var/log has only 40MB and Home directory has 3GB of space(so I believe that's not a problem). Other than that what I can clean up to make space.

```
[user@host]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_inamivm-lv_root
                       18G   17G     0 100% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   71M  389M  16% /boot
```

I am in a debian machine.

**UPDATE1:**

output of  `cd /; du -sxh *`

```
6.1M    bin
61M     boot
156K    dev
22M        etc
3.3G    home
306M    lib
18M     lib64
16K     lost+found
4.0K    media
4.0K    mnt
408K    opt
du: cannot access `proc/18605/task/18605/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/18605/task/18605/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/18605/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/18605/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0       proc
208K    root
9.7M    sbin
0       selinux
4.0K    srv
0       sys
8.0K    tmp
536M    usr
187M    var
```

**Update2**

Output of `ls -la /`

```
dr-xr-xr-x.  22 root root  4096 Aug  7 08:42 .
dr-xr-xr-x.  22 root root  4096 Aug  7 08:42 ..
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root     0 Aug  7 08:42 .autofsck
dr-xr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Mar 28 16:53 bin
dr-xr-xr-x.   5 root root  1024 Mar 28 16:54 boot
drwxr-xr-x.  16 root root  3580 Sep  9 03:13 dev
drwxr-xr-x.  69 root root  4096 Aug 23 09:19 etc
drwxr-xr-x.   9 root root  4096 Jun 29 16:10 home
dr-xr-xr-x.   8 root root  4096 Mar  7  2012 lib
dr-xr-xr-x.   9 root root 12288 Mar 28 16:53 lib64
drwx------.   2 root root 16384 Mar  7  2012 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Sep 23  2011 media
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Sep 23  2011 mnt
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root  4096 Mar  7  2012 opt
dr-xr-xr-x. 355 root root     0 Aug  7 08:42 proc
dr-xr-x---.   5 root root  4096 Aug 17 18:27 root
dr-xr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 May  2 09:13 sbin
drwxr-xr-x.   7 root root     0 Aug  7 08:42 selinux
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Sep 23  2011 srv
drwxr-xr-x.  13 root root     0 Aug  7 08:42 sys
drwxrwxrwt.   3 root root  4096 Sep 13 03:37 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.  13 root root  4096 Mar 28 17:53 usr
drwxr-xr-x.  18 root root  4096 Mar  7  2012 var
```

Comment: There is no universal answer here. Run following commands as root, wait for a while and paste your results: `cd /; du -sxh *`. It will sum up the size of all main directories on your server. Then, we will have a clue. You can also enter this big directory with cd and run du command inside of it to get deeper.

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski Thanks for a quick reply. I have updated the question with output of `cd /; du -sxh *`

Comment: @Subhransu Based on what you are seeing it appears as if you have a file that has been removed while still open.

Comment: @Karlson I really don't understand **if you have a file that has been removed while still open** . Please explain. Please let me know what other output could be viable so that you can help me.

Comment: Did you remove any big files recently? Like log files or something like this?

Comment: Maybe you have files in the /-directory? You might want to check with `ls -la /`

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski No, I have not deleted any log file(as I do not know what file to delete).

Comment: Well, the easiest way to find out would be to reboot the server. It would kill all the processes so all the files would be closed which would delete them. You can try to restart syslogd, just in case with `/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart` and since you have a lot of apache processes, i would also try to restart apache itself with `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. Check if it make some free space on your filesystem.

Comment: @Subhransu The situation is simple.  Process `foo` has opened a file called `bar` then user Subharansu came in and did `rm -f bar`.  File is still opened by the running process `foo` and space it claims is unavailable for use until `foo` exits.

Comment: You can also check the output of `lsof  | awk ' { print $8,$9 }' | sort -n | uniq | tail -n 30`

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski The system not able understand the command `bash: lsof: command not found` and I have tried it including the path `/usr/sbin/lsof` but still not able to recognize the command. Is it safe to do `reboot` if system do not have any storage space?

Comment: It is possible that you don't have this command installed, then. It should be safe to reboot without storage space. But as I don't know what exactly happened on your system, I can't guarantee that it will boot up correctly (but it should).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best way of finding out disk consuming, is using graphical software like `baobab`:

Launch it with `sudo baobab /`

[image]

Comment: Will it work in remote server ?

Comment: @Subhransu Sure, if you connect with X forwarding (`ssh -X` or `ForwardX11 yes` in `~/.ssh/config`). However, if it isn't installed you might not have enough space to install it and the requisite directory.

Comment: See [my answer below](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110114/9760) for a graphical tool that does not require an X server and requires very little server space.

Answer (score 55):

[daisy's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48066/9760) to use a graphical tool to visually find large files and directories is probably the best method. **However, do note that "graphical tool" does not mean "requires an X server"!** The wonderful `ncdu` program provides the graphical output in the CLI, and works perfectly on remote servers via SSH:

```
$ ncdu /

.  43.7GiB [##########] /home
.   5.9GiB [#         ] /usr
    1.1GiB [          ] /lib
.   1.1GiB [          ] /var
  736.9MiB [          ] /opt
. 324.6MiB [          ] /tmp
  218.4MiB [          ] /boot
.  63.8MiB [          ] /etc
   10.0MiB [          ] /sbin
    8.8MiB [          ] /bin
    3.3MiB [          ] /lib32
.   1.0MiB [          ] /run
   64.0KiB [          ] /build
!  16.0KiB [          ] /lost+found
    8.0KiB [          ] /media
    8.0KiB [          ] /mnt
    8.0KiB [          ] /.config
    4.0KiB [          ] /dev
    4.0KiB [          ] /lib64
e   4.0KiB [          ] /srv
e   4.0KiB [          ] /selinux
!   4.0KiB [          ] /root
e   4.0KiB [          ] /cdrom
.   0.0  B [          ] /proc
.   0.0  B [          ] /sys
@   0.0  B [          ]  initrd.img.old
@   0.0  B [          ]  initrd.img
@   0.0  B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
```

Then, after entering `/var/` for instance:

```
. 395.3MiB [##########] /tmp
. 365.0MiB [######### ] /cache
. 297.8MiB [#######   ] /lib
   16.1MiB [          ] /backups
.   8.0MiB [          ] /log
.  56.0KiB [          ] /spool
   40.0KiB [          ] /games
    8.0KiB [          ] /www
e   4.0KiB [          ] /opt
e   4.0KiB [          ] /mail
e   4.0KiB [          ] /local
e   4.0KiB [          ] /crash
@   0.0  B [          ]  lock
@   0.0  B [          ]  run
```

Install easily on Debian or Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ncdu
```

Install easily on CentOS as root:

```
# yum install ncdu
```

Comment: Oh wow, didn't know `ncdu` existed. All this time, I use `du -sh ./* 2> /dev/null | sort -rh`.

Answer (score 7):

Debian offers a utility called `cruft` IIRC that lists files that could possibly be uneeded on your system.

Comment: How can that be used?

Answer (score 6):

make a new file in `/bin` called `treesize`

```
chmod +x /bin/treesize
```

paste this in it.

```sh
#/bin/sh
du -k --max-depth=1 | sort -nr | awk '
     BEGIN {
        split("KB,MB,GB,TB", Units, ",");
     }
     {
        u = 1;
        while ($1 >= 1024) {
           $1 = $1 / 1024;
           u += 1
        }
        $1 = sprintf("%.1f %s", $1, Units[u]);
        print $0;
     }
    '
```

Output looks like this.

```
#treesize
3.0 GB .
1.1 GB ./usr
759.9 MB ./var
353.3 MB ./root
307.1 MB ./opt
270.7 MB ./lib
98.6 MB ./home
60.1 MB ./boot
9.8 MB ./etc
8.3 MB ./bin
8.1 MB ./sbin
268.0 KB ./run
40.0 KB ./tmp
16.0 KB ./lost+found
```

Comment: or this `du -hsx /* | sort -rh | head -n 40`

Comment: @Alejandro: it's not really the same - at all.

Comment: I like this - very neat!

Answer (score 5):

You can check for deleted files with `lsof | grep -i deleted` 
Then you can see if a process is hanging on to an inode that you think was deleted. If so, restart the parent process to release the old (deleted) file.

Answer (score 5):

I've found some very useful commands on [this post at Askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/a/6014/48105). Paraphrasing:

- Show top 10 biggest subdirs in the current dir: `du -sk * | sort -nr | head -10`
- Use filelight/kDirStat/baobab to see where the disk space is going visually
- Check if you have old kernels for deletion: `ls -lh /boot`
- Clean packages: `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`
- See list of all installed packages, sorted by size: `dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Installed-Size} ${Package}\n' | sort -nr | less`
- Clean unused language files with translations: `sudo apt-get install localepurge`
- Check content of /var/tmp/: `du -sh /var/tmp/`
- Check also `man deborphan`
- Search for big files: `find / -type f -size +1024k` or `find / -size +50000  -exec ls -lahg {} \;`

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the biggest files on your FS and maybe you will find there some files which can be deleted.

```
find / -xdev -type f -size +100000c -exec ls -la {} \; 2>/dev/null | sort -nk5 | tail -20
```

If you need longer output, just change number after tail command.

Please post output from:

```
df -h /
du -shx /
```

Both commands should show similar used space of your FS.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -atime +180 | xargs ls -al | sort -u -n -k5 | numfmt --to=iec --field=5
```

- find all files in `.` whos access time is over 180 days old
- show file size
- sort by 5th column, numerical
- format 5th column to human readable

Useful links about access time:

- https://superuser.com/questions/464290/why-is-cat-not-changing-the-access-time
- [timestamp, modification time, and created time of a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2464/timestamp-modification-time-and-created-time-of-a-file)