# Is there an easy way to clean up useless files?

Tags: debian, gnome

Is there a command or an application i can download or run that would clean up and uninstall useless and unused files? I just want to free up some space on my machine, and that is my main goal.

Comment: Are any of these of any help? See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48059/how-to-clean-up-unnecessary-files?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an application called [BleachBit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bleachbit/)

it has following features:

- Clear the memory and swap on Linux
- Delete broken shortcuts on Linux
- Delete the Firefox URL history without deleting the whole file—with
  optional shredding
- Delete Linux localizations: delete languages you don't use. More
  powerful than localepurge and available on more Linux distributions.
- Clean APT for Debian, Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, and Linux Mint
- Find widely-scattered junk such as Thumbs.db and .DS_Store files.
- Execute yum clean for CentOS, Fedora, and Red Hat to remove cached
  package data
- Delete Windows registry keys—often where MRU (most recently used)
  lists are stored
- Delete the OpenOffice.org recent documents list without deleting the
  whole Common.xcu file
- Overwrite free disk space to hide previously files
- Vacuum Firefox, Google Chrome, Liferea, Thunderbird, and Yum
  databases: shrink files without removing data to save space and
  improve speed
- Surgically remove private information from .ini and JSON
  configuration files and SQLite3 databases without deleting the whole
  file
- Overwrite data in SQLite3 before deleting it to prevent recovery
  (optional)