# Run Out Of Space On /dev/sda2

Tags: linux, linux-mint, devices

My Linux (Mint  13) laptop reported that 'The volume "Fiilesystem root" has only 0 bytes disk space remaining'. When I ran a 'df' I got the following result:-

```
HP-255-G1-Notebook-PC # df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       28836860 27372200         0 100% /
udev             1810632        4   1810628   1% /dev
tmpfs             727768      980    726788   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1819416       76   1819340   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda3      692800400 68383328 589741516  11% /home
overflow            1024       16      1008   2% /tmp
```

I suspect that the system was originally configured with insufficient space on /dev/sda2. Is it possible to reconfigure this without doing a complete reinstall?

Thank you.

Comment: You should have a look at `gparted`.

Comment: Here you go it might be helpful "https://thewiringcloset.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/extending-a-root-filesystem-in-linux-without-lvm/"

Comment: You might have some huge files that are taking up space on your root partition that don't need to be there. [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48059/how-to-clean-up-unnecessary-files) has some suggestions for finding them. Also, it might be worthwhile running [bleachbit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: are /home and / using LVM?

Comment: The [package cache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65549/var-cache-apt-archives-occupying-huge-space) is a fairly frequent offender for eating space. You may just need to manage `/var/cache/`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to change partitioning under any of GNU/Linux OS with `gparted` without reintstalling the OS. You will need to download from [gpated](http://gparted.org)
web site [Live CD/USB](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) image, make a bootable media with it and load machine from there. If you have enough free space before or after the partition you can easily resize it in particular enlarge. Save any precious data before.

Comment: Will `gparted` migrate their data? I ask because I doubt that the installer left much (if any) space between `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3`.

Comment: If it is possible to move the whole /dev/sda3 then it goes

Comment: There are several ways you could proceed, but first we need to look at your partitioning of the disk, what does "cfdisk /dev/sda" report?