# Linux disk usage

Tags: disk-usage

I'm trying to find out what folders occupy / partition.
I see that lots of disk space goes to jenkins directory

```
sudo du -sh /home/jenkins
289G    /home/jenkins
```

When I examine jenkins directory folder I get the largest folder is:

```
sudo du -sh /home/jenkins/*
137G    /home/jenkins/jobs
```

And rest of the folders are relatively small, tens of K/M...
In total there are 50 folders under /home/jenkins.

How can I find who "eats" the space?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure the du command is also looking at hidden files.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "eats".  Are you trying to find the largest files within `/home/jenkins/jobs`?  You also mentioned partitions, are you trying to find out what partitions they live on?

Comment: see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48059/how-to-clean-up-unnecessary-files

Comment: Thanks for your help. Indeed it was a hidden maven local repository .m2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between: `sudo du -sh /home/jenkins` and `sudo du -sh /home/jenkins/*` is that in almost all shells (with the default setttings), `*` does not include hidden files or directories. Hidden means names starting with a period (e.g., if there is a `/home/jenkins/.temp/`, that would not be included in the second `du`).

So it'd appear you have about 289-137=152 GiB of hidden files. The easiest way to find out where they are is something like this:

```shell
sudo du -m /home/jenkins | sort -nr | less
```

Taking off the `-s` will make `du` show you the subdirectories everything is in, which sounds like what you want. That'll include hidden ones. If that still doesn't find it, add an `-a`:

```shell
sudo du -am /home/jenkins | sort -nr | less
```

that will additionally show individual files, in case you have a few very large hidden files. It will probably also take a bit longer to run (adding files often greatly expands the output).

There are also graphical frontends you can use; personally, I use xdiskusage (but maybe just because I've been using it forever):

```shell
sudo du -am /home/jenkins | xdiskusage -
```

Answer (score 0):

Look inside jobs with following command

```
du -sm /home/jenkins/jobs/* |sort -nr
```

I have suggested a reverse sort so largest are last, just above your new command line, `-n` specifies a numeric comparison, du output is set to always show as MB so that lines can be sorted sensibly.

edit: someone suggested also adding `-a` to `du` to count all files (including hidden) but comment has disappeared ?

Comment: Nice addition. Tks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion—that was my comment, but then I realized I had a lot more suggestions than would fit in a comment so added my own answer (and deleted my comment).

Answer (score 0):

Use find command:

```
find /home/jenkins/jobs/ -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

Comment: hopefully they don't have hundreds of 99Mb files!

Answer (score 0):

For a quick, graphical overview you can use `Filelight`, which makes it easy to follow the paths with the largest share of disk usage, or a similar utility:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-analyze-your-disk-usage-pattern-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these three options together can achieve the results that you're expecting:

> **-s, --summarize**
>
> display only a total for each argument
>
> **-c, --total**
>
> produce a grand total
>
> **-h, --human-readable**
>
> print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)

```
linus@host: / $ sudo du -sch *
9,8M    bin
362M    boot
4,0K    cdrom
12K     dev
32K     docker
170M    etc
9,5G    data
36G     home
0       initrd.img
0       initrd.img.old
2,9G    lib
4,4M    lib64
16K     lost+found
84G     media
12K     mnt
1,1G    opt
du: cannot access ‘proc/6836/task/6836/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/6836/task/6836/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/6836/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/6836/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
0       proc
19M     root
du: cannot access ‘run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
1,7M    run
13M     sbin
4,0K    srv
0       sys
52K     tmp
7,5G    usr
14G     var
0       vmlinuz
0       vmlinuz.old

154G    total
```