# 20 GB boot drive?

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I have a 20 GB boot drive yet I keep getting low mem notices - it uses 18 GB+. Is that correct? I see other posts that people have much smaller boot drives w/o problems. It usually only happens when I install new software. BTW, I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

```
ls -sh
total 927M
4.0K bin       0 dev      0 initrd.img      4.0K lib32       4.0K media     0 proc   12K sbin  927M swapfile  4.0K usr         0 vmlinuz.old
4.0K boot    12K etc      0 initrd.img.old  4.0K lib64       4.0K mnt    4.0K root  4.0K snap     0 sys       4.0K var
4.0K cdrom  4.0K home  4.0K lib              16K lost+found  4.0K opt       0 run   4.0K srv   4.0K tmp          0 vmlinuz

df /boot
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       20054232 17657208   1355260  93% /

du -hxd1 /boot
8.0M    /boot/grub
58M /boot

ls -sh /boot
total 50M
220K config-5.0.0-23-generic  4.0K grub    180K memtest86+.bin  184K memtest86+_multiboot.bin     8.4M vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic 4.0K efi
```

Comment: You say _I keep getting low mem notices_. From what?  Disk space and memory are different things...

Comment: Maybe wrong wording. The point my boot drive get low on disk space. Why, with that much size, is it getting full? I have one kernal installed.

Comment: 20 **GB**? Maybe start with checking what's on it - `df /boot`, `du -hxd1 /boot`, `ls -sh /boot`,etc. (Assuming your boot drive is mounted on `/boot`)

Comment: df /boot
    Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sda1       20054232 17657208   1355260  93% /

    du -hxd1 /boot
    8.0M /boot/grub
    58M /boot

    ls -sh /boot
    total 50M
    220K config-5.0.0-23-generic  4.0K grub    180K memtest86+.bin  184K memtest86+_multiboot.bin     8.4M vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic 4.0K efi

Comment: See also https://imgur.com/a/BURoi0S

Comment: A bunch of old kernels, perhaps? Some distros don't delete old kernels unless you tell them to, such as Ubuntu. `sudo apt autoremove` should take care of those - if that's indeed the issue. It'll also keep a copy of the previous kernel so that you have a fallback.

Comment: No, I only have the one kernel so I don't know. A check of the disk shows the /boot drive is only using 59.9 MB. ???

Comment: It's a bit drastic, but you can boot to a live instance (via USB), copy the data off (you can put it anywhere temporarily), format the partition, and put your files back. There's something definitely amiss, though I'd like to see the output of `ls -sh` entirely (by [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/604706/edit) your post and using the code markup) just to make sure I see it completely.

Comment: Yeah, that what I'm thinking. I added the code above. BTW, how much space should the boot drive have?

Comment: Something is amiss. You said /boot drive, but I see things like /Documents and /Downloads. Those should be on a different partition - if you have the normal /boot drive. Why is all that stuff on the /boot partition?

Comment: Further: To be honest, you're better off backing up your data, wiping all your partitions, installing again, and restoring your backed up data. You have all your files on the /boot partition. If you want a simple/effective method,  you can just let the installer use all the disk space and have a single partition. Modern Linux distros can do that just fine.

Comment: I was wrong. I have re-entered the correct code above. My fault.

Comment: Q: Is this feasible? I want to move the /home to a separate drive.  https://samwedge.uk/posts/mounting-linux-mint-home-directory-on-different-drive/

Comment: You don't have a separate boot partition, at least not in the sense that `/boot` is on a separate partition. You have single root partition which contains everything.

Comment: If moving /home, detailed instrucitons: To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2343317

Comment: It's not an external drive. It's internal. I thought my link above had some simple instructions, no?

Comment: Related: [How to clean up unnecessary files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48059/how-to-clean-up-unnecessary-files)