# Linux - File change time versus modification time

Tags: ubuntu, stat

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, though I'd imagine this question spans all Linux variants. In the manpage for the `stat` command, there are two (four) formatting options that appear to mean the same thing:

> The valid format sequences for files (without --file-system):
>
> ...
>
> %y     Time of last modification, human-readable
>
> %Y     Time of last modification, seconds since Epoch
>
> %z     Time of last change, human-readable
>
> %Z     Time of last change, seconds since Epoch

However, these values aren't always equal. For example, `stat --printf="%y\n%z\n" /usr/local` on my system outputs the following:

> 2012-04-26 10:29:13.000000000 -0500
>
> 2013-05-06 18:08:19.000000000 -0500

So what is the difference between "change time" and "modification time"?

Comment: Please refer SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79809/what-is-the-difference-between-file-modification-time-and-file-changed-time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [timestamp, modification time, and created time of a file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2464/timestamp-modification-time-and-created-time-of-a-file)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Last modification time - the last time the file was modified (content has been modified)

Last change time - the last time /metadata/ of the file was changed (e.g. permissions)

Comment: It also has to be noted that mtime can be set to anything you want, ctime can't.

Comment: @Halfgaar could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: If you copy a file with `cp -a` or `rsync --archive`, you copy as much of the meta data as you can. The mtime will be copied too. The ctime is not however, because there is no way for `cp` or `rsync` to set it. See [this article](http://www.halfgaar.net/backing-up-unix) I wrote for more details.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that change time is essentially the iNode modification time.