# What does when the file's status was last changed mean?

Tags: files, timestamps

I'm reading about `find` and for one of the tests (-cnewer file) it reads:

> File's status was last changed more recently than file was modified.

What is the file's status?  It's obviously a date, but in general what does it mean?

Comment: Have a look to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2464/timestamp-modification-time-and-created-time-of-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's referring to the time when the inode of the file was last changed. In the context of `-cnewer` of `find`, ***status*** means ***inode***.

You can read more about [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), what they are and what they contain.

Comment: So an inode is a number that unique identifies an object in the file system (a directory, symlink, hard link, or file) (it's number not it's name, which can be seen with `ls -lai`). The inode number doesn't change when you rename or write to a file, so what would change the inode?  `fsck` ?

Comment: @leeand00 The inode number will remain the same but the things that inode contains e.g. last modification time, permissions, ownership etc can be changed by operations as you an imagine..`find` and all other tools refer to these changes of inode contents not the inode number of the file.....

Comment: So a status change constitutes the last date that a change was made to the metadata of a file?

Comment: @leeand00 spot on..