# Change last edited date

Tags: files, date, timestamps

How can I change the last edited date of a file?
There doesn't seem to be anything like:

```
chlastediteddate  12/7/12 file
```

What command can do this? Is there a way to do this without changing what the computer thinks is the date, editing the file, and correcting what the computer thinks is the date?

Comment: Dupe of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2464/timestamp-modification-time-and-created-time-of-a-file/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `touch` with the option `-d` (or `--date`)

> touch - change file timestamp
>
> (...)
>
> -d, --date=STRING
>
> parse STRING and use it instead of current time

For example:

```
touch -d '2016-01-15 22:41:18' file
```

or even

```
touch -d '3 months ago' file
```

As always `man touch` is your friend.