# Changing a file's modified date based on date in file name

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, timestamps

I have a directory full of photos with file names in this format: 
`IMG-20160305-WA0001.jpg`. The date taken is obviously in the file title.
Unfortunately the date modified on all files is today.  I want to set them back to the correct date.

I am thinking of a `bash` script that would extract the date portion in the name and then  for example `touch -a -m -t 201603050900 IMG-20160305-WA0000.jpg` for each file in  turn (using correct date  for each one).  The time of day does not matter.

Comment: And your question is... what ? Please do not make us guess here.

Comment: Keep on thinking.  ;)  Alternatively, you can [edit your post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/278433/edit) so that it actually contains a question.  Fair?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change last edited date](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276805/change-last-edited-date)

Comment: @John That's not a duplicate. That question explains how to set a file's date, not how to do it automatically based on the file name.

Answer (score 10):

Example using `bash` string manipulation only to extract the date:

```
#!/bin/bash

for name in IMG-[0-9]*.jpg; do
    touch -amt ${name:4:8}0900 "$name"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

From your example, assuming that all of the files *have* a valid *`yyyymmdd`* date, you can extract the date from the filename and apply that in the command cited:

```
#!/bin/bash
for name in IMG-*-W*.jpg
do
    date="$(echo "$name" | sed -e 's/^IMG-//' -e 's/-W.*//')"
    touch -a -m -t ${date}0900 "$name"
done
```

If some file hasn't a valid date, that is more work.  But you can test that in bash with a regular expression.