# if last 4 file size of a directory are same with each other then exit otheriwse continue

Tags: shell-script

Please give me any shell bash script that will help me doing following task:

if last added 4 file size of a directory  are same with each other then exit other wise continue

Example :

```
ls -l $dir_path | awk '{print $5}' | tail -4
```

if the 4 printed values are same to each other then exit otherwise continue.

Comment: can you explain little bit more, it's not clear to me

Comment: Unix & Linux SE is not a script writing service.

Comment: In order to get help with you script writing abilities, please show us what you tried and give details on why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
zsh -c 'zmodload zsh/stat
  [[ $(zstat -N +size -- *(.om[1,4])) =~ $'\''(.*)\n\\1\n\\1\n\\1'\'' ]]' && exit
```

Would exit if the 4 newest non-hidden regular files in the current directory all have the same size.

On a GNU system, you could also do:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -type f -printf '%T@ %s\n' |
  sort -rn |
  awk 'NR == 1 {v = $0}; v != $0 {exit}; NR == 4 {exit 1}' || exit
```

POSIXly:

```
ls -tnq -- "$dir_path" |
  awk '!/^-/ {next}
       n++ == 0 {v = $5}
       v != $5 {exit}
       n == 4 {exit 1}' || exit
```

If like in your own approach, instead of the 4 newest ones, you want the last 4 (regardless of whether they're regular files or symlinks or sockets...) in the `ls` output (which is an alphabetically sorted list), you can do (still POSIXly):

```
ls -rnq -- "$dir_path" |
  awk 'NR == 1 {next}
       NR == 2 {v = $5}
       v != $5 {exit}
       NR > 4 {exit 1}' || exit
```

Comment: OP wants bash, not zsh...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling well spotted, updated.

Comment: Well, that's one way of solving that... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ls -c` to sort by [ctime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2464/timestamp-modification-time-and-created-time-of-a-file), and `uniq` to see if they're the same.

```
ls -crntq | tail -4 | awk '{print $5}' | uniq -c | grep -q "^\s*4\s" && exit
```

Comment: Note that `ls -s` gives the file disk usage, not the file size.

Comment: You'd want to pass the `-q` option to avoid problems with filenames containing newline characters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas   Bah, I'll have to use the longer output for the size-in-bytes. My version of `ls`  (GNU coreutils 8.21) had already changed the newlines to `?`, so `-q` made no difference, but I'll include that for completeness.

Comment: Without `-q`, the newline is only turned to `?` when the output doesn't go to a terminal, so typically, not when fed to tail via a pipe.