# Finding the newest .srt in a directory and storing it in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm trying to write a script that renames the subtitles to the same name as the movie file is.

I'm currently stuck at getting the .srt filename into a variable.
Currently I'm seeking the smallest file in the directory with:

```
srtnametmp="$(basename $(find . -name '*.srt' -maxdepth 1 -type f  -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n -r| tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'))"
```

However, it can be more than one .srt in the same directory, so I was thinking about finding the newest .srt (by creation time).
Now I've been searching for 5-ish hours, tested several solutions, but I never got the result (only the filename) stuck to the variable $srtnametmp
Now I'm little lost and looking for help.

Comment: Are you working on a filesystem that even stores a creation/birth timestamp on files?

Comment: Isn't all doing that? I can at least see the information on the desktop, and since the desktop can find when a file is created, so should the bash be able to do so... At least I think so..

Answer (score 0):

Below script can be used to get newest `srt` file

```
#!/bin/bash
srt_dir="/home/$USER/Downloads/"
file_type="srt"
srtnametmp=`ls -t1 $srt_dir | grep $file_type | head -1`
echo $srtnametmp
```

---

```
Happy Scripting
```

Comment: Thx, but that script gets the last modified file, not the last created. When unpacking from zip Linux only sets the created parameter, last modified is kept from the original.

Comment: @JoBe If you use `unzip` to unzip, add option `-DD` to skip restoration of timestamps.

Comment: Why didn't I think about that solution.. That solved my issue, but is there anyway to get the creation date?

Comment: I don't know about creation time. Maybe what you really want is [change time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2465/391836)? For that you could use `find` with `-printf '%CY%Cj%CT %f\n'`

Comment: Went through some more posts, it says that creation time is not stored on many filesystems in Unix. I think last modified time changed with `-DD` will work for you.

Comment: Strange, because when you look in the properties on the desktop, there is a creation date see https://dropbox.gr1.se/crdate.png  or am I completely wrong?  Your solution works, if I use the -DD during extraction

Comment: @JoBe What's the output when you [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) the file? Does the `Change` time from `stat` correspond to to that "`Created`" time? What program is that in the screenshot?

Comment: Stat says: birth: -   the screenshot is from the desktop, menu/properties

Comment: @JoBe Does the following do what you want?: `srtnametmp=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.srt' -type f -printf '%CY%Cj%CT %f\n' | sort -nr | sed '1{s/^[^ ]* //;q}')`

Comment: Sheezus, that's a long string, but it appears to do the job!